# Display apex class code on click of Show button

Tags: salesforce

I have a dynamic picklist field that contains all the apex classes name that are in my org. There is a "Show" button on the page as well. Now if a user selects a value from this picklist and clicks on Show button, the apex code of that class should get displayed below.
Pls suggest how can I implement it in my VF page.

Thanks!

```
<apex:form >
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedClass}" size="5">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!ClassList}" ></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:commandButton action="{!show}" value="Show" id="Button"/>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="My Current Class">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could query the `body` field of the `ApexClass` object for what you're looking for:

```
public class SomeController  {

    private List<ApexClass> allApexClasses;
    public String selectedClass {public get; public set;}
    public String apexCodeOutput {public get; private set;}

    public SomeController() {
        // only select classes that aren't part of a managed package, since you won't be able to view the body
        allApexClasses = [select id, name, body from ApexClass where lengthwithoutcomments <> -1 order by name asc];
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getClassList() {
        List<SelectOption> opts = new List<SelectOption> opts;
        for ( ApexClass ac : allApexClasses )
            opts.add(new SelectOption(ac.Id, ac.Name));
        return opts;
    }

    public PageReference show() {
        if ( selectedClass != null ) {
            Id classId = (Id) selectedClass;
            for ( ApexClass ac : allApexClasses ) {
                if ( classId == ac.Id ) {
                    apexCodeOutput = ac.body;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then in your VF page, just rerender the output code when clicking the button. You'll want to use a `<pre>` tag around the code to preserve spacing so the code is readable.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedClass}" size="5">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ClassList}" ></apex:selectOptions>
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!show}" value="Show" rerender="apexoutput" id="Button"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Current Class">
            <apex:outputPanel id="apexoutput">
                <pre>{!apexcodeoutput}</pre>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```